# SharePoint 2013 Workflow - Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features'

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, workflow, error, deployment

When I deploy my workflow.. I get the following error... Any idea what Can be causing this?

> Error 10  Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Microsoft.Workflow.Client.WorkflowManagementException: Exception thrown from the messaging layer. For more details, please see the server logs. HTTP headers received from the server - ActivityId: fe4c8406-d339-4eae-b223-7ede5ce4226c. NodeId: PORTAL-DEV. Scope: /SharePoint/default/ebe5a934-c51d-4615-9530-eafd0801150a/b39daf99-7d5b-4a50-b5e3-09f97ba59a7b. Client ActivityId : 880d11d4-5834-4e86-be83-e302614b0783. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.

I check many places for the solution but no luck :(!

I do have the "Workflow Management Site" in IIS up and running...

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did a complete re-installation with the following power shell script to Configure the App Domain:

```
net start spadminv4
net start sptimerv4
Set-SPAppDomain "<app domain name>"
Get-SPServiceInstance | where{$_.GetType().Name -eq "AppManagementServiceInstance" -or $_.GetType().Name -eq "SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceInstance"} | Start-SPServiceInstance
Get-SPServiceInstance | where{$_.GetType().Name -eq "AppManagementServiceInstance" -or $_.GetType().Name -eq "SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceInstance"}
$account = Get-SPManagedAccount "<managed user account>" 
$appPoolSubSvc = New-SPServiceApplicationPool -Name SettingsServiceAppPool -Account $account
$appPoolAppSvc = New-SPServiceApplicationPool -Name AppServiceAppPool -Account $account
$appSubSvc = New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplication –ApplicationPool $appPoolSubSvc –Name SettingsServiceApp –DatabaseName SettingsServiceDB 
$proxySubSvc = New-SPSubscriptionSettingsServiceApplicationProxy –ServiceApplication $appSubSvc
$appAppSvc = New-SPAppManagementServiceApplication -ApplicationPool $appPoolAppSvc -Name AppServiceApp -DatabaseName AppServiceDB
$proxyAppSvc = New-SPAppManagementServiceApplicationProxy -ServiceApplication $appAppSvc
Set-SPAppSiteSubscriptionName -Name "app" -Confirm:$false
```

and finally registered the workflow service with the site

```
Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite http://portal-dev/ -WorkflowHostUri http://portal-dev:12291 -AllowOAuthHttp -Force
```

If any amendments need to be made, feel free to comment!